# Session Issue in ashx

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am facing issue with the session. I am able to store session in ashx page by Implementing  IRequiresSessionState but when i am redirecting from ashx to aspx page. In aspx page, I am not able to get that session value. I am using **response.redirect(Path,false)** for redirect to another page.

Comment: Are that ashx and aspx in the same application and are you using the same hostname+port to access both?

Comment: Yes both are in same application and i am not using port no to access the handler and aspx page.